# Could not load type 'System.Net.Security.SslStream'

Tags: c#, linux, mono, npgsql

I've this simple C# program:

```
using Npgsql;
public class App {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    const string CONNECTION_STRING = "Host=myserver;Username=mylogin;Password=mypass;Database=mydatabase";
    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING)) {
      conn.Open();
    }
  }
}
```

and I compile it with mono (mcs):

```
mcs -target:exe -lib:bin -r:System.Data.dll -r:Npgsql.dll -r:System.dll -r:Mono.Security.dll -out:bin/ssl.exe src/App.cs
```

when I execute, an error thrown:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Net.Security.SslStream' from assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
  at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open () <0x4155f7f0 + 0x00115> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.GetPooledConnector (Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection Connection) <0x4155c8d0 + 0x00a4f> in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Net.Security.SslStream' from assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
  at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open () <0x4155f7f0 + 0x00115> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.GetPooledConnector (Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection Connection) <0x4155c8d0 + 0x00a4f> in <filename unknown>:0
```

My Npgsql.dll version

```
$ monop2 -r Npgsql.dll 

Assembly Information:
Npgsql
Version=2.2.0.0
Culture=neutral
PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7
```

My compiler:

```
$ mcs --version
Mono C# compiler version 4.4.0.0

$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.4.0 (Stable 4.4.0.40/f8474c4 Mon Mar 28 12:22:29 UTC 2016)
Copyright (`u`C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
TLS:           __thread
SIGSEGV:       altstack
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  amd64
Disabled:      none
Misc:          softdebug 
LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
GC:            sgen
```

Finally, my environment:

```
$ uname --all
Linux abe 4.5.0-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 15 09:41:03 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have one question - do you have library Mono.Security.dll inside bin folder? If so, please delete it and try again.

Comment: Yes, I've  Mono.Security.dll in bin. After deleting it works! Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem, and this seems to be recent (probably related to mono's latest updates).

Comment: I had the same issue in Linux using JetBrains Rider. The dll was in the service folder. Deleting the file did not work. The dll was copied over again during build. I edited /packages/Npgsql.2.2.2/net45/Npgsql.xml and comment out six lines for Mono Security. That also did not work. I renamed /packages/Npgsql.2.2.2/net45/Mono.Security.dll to junk.Mono.Security.dll.junk, and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

As PiKos pointed out, the culprit is the `Mono.Security.dll` embedded by the Npgsql 2.x NuGet package. Deleting it in your bin directory indeed solves this issue but you have to do it manually every time you clean and rebuild your solution.

Instead of deleting it, I chose to *fix* the Npgsql 2.2.7 package inside `~/.nuget/packages/npgsql/2.2.7/lib/net45` by renaming `Mono.Security.dll` to `Mono.Security.dll.original` and adding a symbolic link to the `Mono.Security.dll` in mono’s GAC. Here’s how my `~/.nuget/packages/npgsql/2.2.7/lib/net45` directory looks like:

```
lrwxr-xr-x Mono.Security.dll -> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll
-rwxrw-rw- Mono.Security.dll.original
-rwxrw-rw- Npgsql.dll
-rwxrw-rw- Npgsql.xml
drwxr-xr-x de
drwxr-xr-x es
drwxr-xr-x fi
drwxr-xr-x fr
drwxr-xr-x ja
drwxr-xr-x zh-CN
```

The advantage of this solution is that it works for **all** your projects referencing the Npgsql NuGet package.

And if you got that dependency on Npgsql 2.2.7 because you chose [Npgsql.EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFramework/2.2.7), then simply use the more recent [EntityFramework6.Npgsql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/) package which has a dependency on Npgsql >= 4.0.2 where this problem does not exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to put this info for people that will get different exception like me, I had:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a type. at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open () [0x0002b] in <filename unknown>:0  at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.GetPooledConnector (Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection Connection) [0x0017e] in <filename unknown>:0
```

on

```
conn.Open();
```

**but PIKos solution works for me too.**

I am using:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.4.0 (tarball Tue Jun 14 13:41:51 UTC 2016)

Npgsql.dll version 2.1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @pikos's response, I discovered one of the assemblies in a nuget package that I'm using shipped it's own `Mono.Security.dll`. However, mono 4.4.1 [moves some of the types out of that assembly](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40482), and likely moves some in as well. Because I did not have an explicit reference to `Mono.Security`, [x|ms]build was resolving the indirect dependency by using the incompatible assembly in my`packages` folder.

To resolve this, without any other workarounds (e.g. deleting assemblies every build), I just added an explicit assembly reference to the system's `Mono.Security`. This forced the 4.4.1 version in the GAC to be used instead. By not using the one from the nuget, I lost the patch that had prompted the builder of the nuget to include their own Mono.Security, but I'm okay with that for now. YMMV.