# Npgsql - Mono.Security.dll - Could not load type of field 'Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection:CertificateSelectionCallback'

Tags: c#, mono, npgsql

I have a c# application that use a Postgres DB. It is in .NET 4.0 and use Npgsql 2.2.7.0, for backward compatibility I cannot change these versions.

It runs fine in Windows and in a linux board with Mono 3.2.8. Now I need to use it in Mono 6.8.0.105.

I receive an error "System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'System.Net.Security.SslStream:provider'" and thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641573/could-not-load-type-system-net-security-sslstream/77321732) I solve it deleting Mono.Security.dll from the application folder.

Now it appers another error:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection:CertificateSelectionCallback' (9) due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000058 from typeref (expected class 'Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.CertificateSelectionCallback' in assembly 'Mono.Security, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756') assembly:Mono.Security, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756 type:Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.CertificateSelectionCallback member:(null)
```

I made some test linking some Mono.Security.dll (found on Mono installation) in application folder but with no success. For another test I am trying to register to System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback but also with no success.

Someone can help my to solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Just an update: If I replace Mono 6.8.0.105 with Mono 5.10.1.20 the problem disappears, so I think the problem is inside last versions of Mono

Just another update: I discovered that if I copy Mono.Security.dll from the GAC of Mono 5.10.1.20 and I put it inside application folder, all works fine also in Mono 6.8.0.105, so I think some classes are been removed in Mono.Security in the upgrade from Mono 5 to 6